# Check box not copying

Tags: excel, checkbox, copy, paste

I'm using a module to copy one sheet to many, but it doesn't copy the check box I have in the sheet, although if I manually select all and copy it does. Can someone explain why its not working in the VBA script, and if possible, how to get it to work?

Here is the script I am running:

```vb
Sub Button4_Click()

Const ExclusionsList As String = "Main,Source," _
        & "Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday"
     
    Dim Wbk As Workbook
    Dim WshSrc As Worksheet
    Dim WshTrg As Worksheet
    Dim Exclusions() As String
    Dim n As Long
    
    Set Wbk = ThisWorkbook
    Set WshSrc = Wbk.Worksheets("Source")
    Exclusions = Split(ExclusionsList, ",")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each WshTrg In Wbk.Worksheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(WshTrg.Name, Exclusions, 0)) Then
            WshSrc.Cells.Copy
            With WshTrg
                .Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
                Application.Goto .Cells(1), 1
            End With
        End If
    Next
    
    Application.Goto Worksheets("Main").Cells(1), 1
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You should use ActiveX checkboxes.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help!